# How to implement SAND architecture using OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to implement Simultaneous ANalysis and Design (SAND) architecture on OpenMDAO with Sellar Problem. I thought of following way to do so -

```
class SellarDis1(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis1, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('y1', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        x1 = params['x']
        y2 = params['y2']
        y1 = unknowns['y1']

        resids['y1'] = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2 - y1

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}

        J['y1','y1'] = 1.0
        J['y1','y2'] = -0.2
        J['y1','z'] = np.array([[2*params['z'][0], 1.0]])
        J['y1','x'] = 1.0

        return J


class SellarDis2(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis2, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('y2', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        pass

    def apply_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        y1 = params['y1']
        y1 = abs(y1)
        y2 = unknowns['y2']

        resids['y2'] = y1**.5 + z1 + z2 - y2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}

        J['y2', 'y2'] = 1.0
        J['y2', 'y1'] = 0.5*params['y1']**-0.5
        J['y2', 'z'] = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])

        return J

class SellarSAND(Group):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarSAND, self).__init__()

        self.add('px', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0,2.0])), promotes=['*'])

        self.add('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['*'])

        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                     z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                 promotes=['*'])

        self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['*'])

        self.nl_solver = NLGaussSeidel()
        self.nl_solver.options['atol'] = 1.0e-12
        self.ln_solver = ScipyGMRES()


top = Problem()
top.root = SellarSAND()

top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
top.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-12

top.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]))
top.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

top.driver.add_objective('obj')
top.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)

top.setup()
tt = time.time()
top.run()


print("\n")
print( "Minimum found at (z1,z2,x) = (%f, %f, %f)" % (top['z'][0], \
                                         top['z'][1], \
                                         top['x']))
print("Coupling vars: %f, %f" % (top['y1'], top['y2']))
print("Minimum objective: ", top['obj'])
print("Elapsed time: ", 1000*(time.time()-tt), "milliseconds")
```

But on running the system I am getting following incorrect result -

```
Iteration limit exceeded    (Exit mode 9)
            Current function value: [ 1.36787944]
            Iterations: 201
            Function evaluations: 2171
            Gradient evaluations: 201
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------


Minimum found at (z1,z2,x) = (5.973519, 0.000000, 0.000000)
Coupling vars: 1.000000, 1.000000
Minimum objective:  1.36787944117
Elapsed time:  21578.5069466 milliseconds
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here? 
Also, are residuals defined in the component class reduced by Solver or Driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT -- I initially implemented All-At-Once, so I've rewritten this. It should now be SAND.

So in my understanding of SAND, the optimizer minimizes the problem by varying the design variables simultaneously with the coupling variables to achieve feasibility and drive the residual constraint to zero.. This means the residual needs to be expressed explicitly so we don't need any implicit components or a solver -- the optimizer does it all. I modified your code as follows:

```
import time

import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, IndepVarComp, ExecComp, NLGaussSeidel, ScipyGMRES, \
     ScipyOptimizer, pyOptSparseDriver


class SellarDis1(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis1, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)

        self.add_output('resid1', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        x1 = params['x']
        y2 = params['y2']
        y1 = params['y1']

        unknowns['resid1'] = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2 - y1

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}

        J['resid1','y1'] = -1.0
        J['resid1','y2'] = -0.2
        J['resid1','z'] = np.array([[2*params['z'][0], 1.0]])
        J['resid1','x'] = 1.0

        return J


class SellarDis2(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarDis2, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_param('y1', val=1.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=1.0)

        self.add_output('resid2', val=1.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

        z1 = params['z'][0]
        z2 = params['z'][1]
        y1 = params['y1']
        y1 = abs(y1)
        y2 = params['y2']

        unknowns['resid2'] = y1**.5 + z1 + z2 - y2

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}

        J['resid2', 'y2'] = -1.0
        J['resid2', 'y1'] = 0.5*params['y1']**-0.5
        J['resid2', 'z'] = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])

        return J

class SellarSAND(Group):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarSAND, self).__init__()

        self.add('px', IndepVarComp('x', 1.0), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('pz', IndepVarComp('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0])), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('py1', IndepVarComp('y1', 1.0), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('py2', IndepVarComp('y2', 1.0), promotes=['*'])

        self.add('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes=['*'])

        self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                     z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                 promotes=['*'])

        self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['*'])
        self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['*'])


top = Problem()
top.root = SellarSAND()

top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
top.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-12

top.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]))
top.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
top.driver.add_desvar('y1', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)
top.driver.add_desvar('y2', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)

top.driver.add_objective('obj')
top.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('resid1', equals=0.0)
top.driver.add_constraint('resid2', equals=0.0)

top.setup()
tt = time.time()
top.run()


print("\n")
print( "Minimum found at (z1,z2,x) = (%f, %f, %f)" % (top['z'][0], \
                                         top['z'][1], \
                                         top['x']))
print("Coupling vars: %f, %f" % (top['d1.y1'], top['d1.y2']))
print("Minimum objective: ", top['obj'])
print("Elapsed time: ", 1000*(time.time()-tt), "milliseconds")
```

You were on the right track; my main change was making it all explicit and declaring the y1 and y2 as des vars.

Doing this, I get

```
Minimum found at (z1,z2,x) = (1.977639, -0.000000, -0.000000)
Coupling vars: 3.160000, 3.755278
('Minimum objective: ', 3.1833939516406136)
('Elapsed time: ', 22.55988121032715, 'milliseconds')
```

Comment: Note, edited my response so that the code is SAND instead of AAO.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what would be different implementation wise between AAO & SAND for this problem. AAO is supposed to have both compatibility constraints between actual & target coupling variables as well as residual constraints. But wouldn't that be redundant for the optimizer?

Comment: For AAO, I made separate components to house the residuals, kept in the data transfer between d1 and 2, and the code for the disciplines d1 and d2 was the same as in the MDF examples. So, the differences are subtle but amount to a little more storage. Overall, i think the number of constraints was the same.